# What is the difference between glEnable and glEnableClientState?

Tags: opengl

What is the difference between glEnable and glEnableClientState? Every time I need a mode set/unset I have to look at the reference to know which of those will accept it. Os there any general rule which says what modes goes into which one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to tibur's answer, in practice the only use of `glEnableClientState` and `glDisableClientState` is for enabling/disabling the builtin fixed-function attribute arrays (like `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`, `GL_NORMAL_ARRAY`, ...). For all other states you use `glEnable` and `glDisable` (or `glEnableVertexAttribArray` and `glDisableVertexAttribArray` for the generic vertex shader attributes).

Comment: If all the arrays are client side, why arrays are faster than begin/end? I thought the graphic card copies them directly from memory, but that cant be client side, right?

Comment: @Dani The original vertex arrays are client state and reside in CPU memory (that's why you only set a pointer to CPU memory in `glVertexPointer` and the like). The performance boost is not only due to not copying from CPU, but to not calling back to the driver for each and every vertex. But you're right in that VBOs (which are the modern way to use arrays) allow you to store arrays in GPU memory. But the old way of enabling the arrays with `glEnableClientState` has been kept.

Comment: @Dani But the fixed function vertex arrays have been deprecated anyway (together with `glEnableClientState`). And the new `glEnableVertexAttribArray` for generic shader attributes has no notion of client or server anymore.

Comment: I'm on mac, there is not even OpenGL-3 here

Comment: @Dani You don't need OpenGL 3 to use shaders and VBOs or to use generic vertex attributes instead of the old builtin attributes. You can perfectly program GL in a modern and future-compatible way in OpenGL 2. It's just that you have to take the right decisions yourself, instead of getting them taken for you by the deprecation model.

Comment: @Dani: Also, MacOSX Lion allows for OpenGL 3.2, core profile.

Answer (score 3):

`glEnable` is used for the set of state that the OpenGL ARB determined represented internal driver state. `glEnableClientState` is for state that represents information that you more directly control. The only client state that existed to be enabled/disabled were the old vertex array states. And those were superceeded by `glEnable/DisableVertexAttribArray`.

The distinction is really quite meaningless since the driver still manages all of this state.

Comment: In the case one uses indirect rendering over GLX, then the driver will not manage all of the state. On the client side the OpenGL/GLX library is responsible to keep track of client state, and on the server side the driver must care about OpenGL state. Thus the distinction. OpenGL-3 has not been fully specified in terms of indirect GLX which is a shame, since the bandwidth savings of Buffer Objects and Tesselation Shaders would make a lot sense of doing OpenGL-3 indirectly.

Answer (score 2):

`glEnable` are server side while `glEnableClientState` are client side. Think at server side as you CPU and client side as your GPU. Globally, vertex arrays only are client side.

Comment: In terms of OpenGL, server side is GPU not CPU and vice-versa right??